# How can one access Accelerometer in windows 10 generic C++ module?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a Java app that uses a native interface to a C++ module to access native API features. The program is running on a windows 10 tablet computer that has an accelerometer.  I want to access the sensor output and pass it to the java program. The windows module is a generic "Win32" module compiled using VC 2015 community edition and the latest windows 10 sdk.

Is this even possible or is the only way through their totally new "Universal App" system that is based on c# .net and xaml "coding" ???

I want subscribe to sensor events and receive callbacks or the tail end of a queue or pipe with the data.

Comment: [Sensor API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/Dd318953(v=vs.85).aspx) with [these `SENSOR_TYPE_ID`s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318985(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: You've got things backwards. The Universal Windows Platform (introduced as the Windows Runtime in Windows 8) is **not** based on .NET. It's a native implementation over the native Win32 API. Windows Runtime types can be projected into different programming languages, like C#, JavaScript, or C++. It's still a native implementation, based on COM.

Comment: @andlabs - got that I was wondering if there is a gerenic C++ api header file and library that gives the C++ code access without having to search for DLL symbols creating import headrs for them or compile something with all that xaml C# and other new macro coding systems the have in the new stuff.  So I could just spawn a thread or register a callback and do it in the generic C-C++ module.  Using ATL for com stuff would be fine if there are interface query method headers and interface headers.

Comment: Your comment does not seem to be in reply to what I posted; were you responding to IInspectable? I posted a pure COM API that predates the Windows Runtime by several years. Is something wrong with it?

Comment: You seem to be still very confused. *"All that XAML C# and other new macro coding systems"* **is** old stuff: COM, essentially. There is no C# in the Windows Runtime. There is no .NET in the Windows Runtime. andlabs gave you the link to the native API. That's what you asked for. What information do you feel is missing?