# How to access Accelerometer on Windows 10/OpenFrameworks?

Tags: c++, windows-10, openframeworks

I'm writing a small program in c++ where I need data from the accelerometer on my laptop. I'm using OpenFrameworks for some other stuff, but found no addon that could help me with this.

There seems to be a Windows API for sensors like this, but all I could find was Wind7/8 stuff, nothing about Windows 10. Also the API that I found is extremely confusing and I wasted hours on it already with nothing to show (probably doesn't work with Win10).

Either a working OF addon, or a short (comprehensible!) guide on how to access sensors in Windows10 would be great help.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure, but could [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760178/how-can-one-access-accelerometer-in-windows-10-generic-c-module#comment62989728_37760178) help ?

Comment: It's the API I was talking about. I'm not sure it's supported like this on Win10, and even if it is, it's very opaque. Non of that code works for me.